# Comparing count in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that will get counts of values based on specific search criteria:

```
Sub WBR()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT") 'no of tickets processed - summary
        [AE43] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT", _
            .Range("G:G"), "<>Not Tested", _
            .Range("U:U"), "Item")
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT") 'not tested tickets - summary
        [AE44] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Not Tested")
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT") 'Tickets moved back- outdated OS and App Versions - summary
        [AE45] = wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Outdated App Version") + wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Outdated OS")
    End With
End Sub
```

Now I need to do a similar function, but not sure how to do it:

- Check in columns `F` and `G` for the count of `COMPATIBLE`
- If `F` has more `COMPATIBLE` then that value should be updated in cell
- Else, if `G` has more count then that should be updated in the same cell.

How do I do this with the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just tack this on the end of your existing code. Simply take the count of `COMPATIBLE` in columns `F` and `G` and set the value of `[AE46]` according to your condition:

```
' compare columns F and G compatible counts
Dim lngFCompatibleCount As Long
Dim lngGCompatibleCount As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")
    lngFCompatibleCount = wf.CountIf(.Range("F:F"), "COMPATIBLE")
    lngGCompatibleCount = wf.CountIf(.Range("G:G"), "COMPATIBLE")
End With

If lngFCompatibleCount > lngGCompatibleCount Then
    [AE46] = lngFCompatibleCount
Else 'not sure about condition where count for F= count for G
    [AE46] = lngGCompatibleCount
End If
```